# Is data validity guaranteed when using java sockets?

Tags: java, validation, sockets, tcp, corruption

Note: I am primarily concerned with data **validity** and not **authenticity**, i.e I care if data becomes corrupt due to transmission error but care less about if a malicious user tries to alter and retransmit packets to the original intended party (something like a MITM attack).

I am recently building a network protocol based upon TCP (specifically using java's `Socket` and `ServerSocket`) and I ran into a little problem regarding how reliable data can be transferred from point A to point B using TCP.

My main concern right now is whether to include a `SHA-2` hash on the payload (and possibly header) data of my custom packet structure. Through some research I've seen that TCP does have its own ECC but I've also heard its not particularly "strong".

Since java's `Socket` is based off a TCP architecture, my questions are:

1. Does the `Socket` class guarantee valid (non-corrupted/lost) data (at least to the certainty that I don't need to include my own data checksum)?
2. Does java itself (through whatever java code infrastructure) provide **additional** validation (over plain-old TCP) to data when its being sent over a TCP connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TCP protocol contains checksums and retransmit machanisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Error_detection) to make sure your data doesn't get corrupted on the way. If a package is damaged (i.e. the checksum doesn't match on the receiving end), the TCP/IP stack will automatically ask the server to send this frame again.

There is no need to do anything at the Socket or Java application layer.

Comment: So you're saying its completely unnecessary to add checksums to my protocol specifications? (I've read that section of the article that you linked prior...)

Comment: Yes, more checksums are a waste of time and bandwidth.

Answer (score 4):

1. TCP does that. Nothing to do with the Socket class.
2. Java doesn't add anything to what TCP does.